# wget - download file from ftp server (with auth) via http proxy (with auth)

Tags: http, curl, proxy, ftp, wget

I want to use wget to download a whole folder from ftp (i know about -r), curl does not allow downloading folder in one request. I have the following syntax for curl working but **can't work out the syntax for even downloading a single file via wget**. The **key things here are that ftp has auth and getting to ftp is via http proxy (with diff credentials)**.

This is the working curl command:
curl  --proxy-anyauth --proxy-user NTADMIN\proxyuser:proxypass --proxy http://httpproxyhost:8080 --anyauth -u ftpuser:ftppass  -v 'ftp://ftphost/file'

What is the equivalent in wget?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use canonical URI format:

```
curl --proxy http://proxyuser:proxypass@httpproxyhost:8080 -v 'ftp://ftpuser:ftppass@ftphost/file'
```

With wget you can use command like this:

```
ftp_proxy=http://proxyuser:proxypass@httpproxyhost:8080 wget ftp://ftpuser:ftppass@ftphost/file
```

Comment: doesn't work, stuck at Connecting to ftphost...       forever

Comment: Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 407 Proxy Authentication Required

Comment: For me it seems like proxy authentication do not work in this case. Have you check username/password for proxy? And if you can do it with `curl` why you search for `wget`?

Comment: username/passw are correct since curl accepts them and if i give bad passw to curl then curl does not work. The reason i search for wget is that it has -r option to download recursive folder but curl does not